# What is the purpose of this inductor and cap on a RF line?

Tags: rf, identification, layout

I'm busy looking at the layout guide for a chip antenna (Taoglas Limited ILA.08).

On their evaluation board, they have parts #6,7 included:
[image]

But in the layout mentioned later in the doc, they are not included:
[image]

What are they for, and do I need to include them?

Note: this is the layout for the RF IO coming from the module that will be connected to the antenna, where C4 is 100pF, L1 is 47nH and R2 is 0Ω[image]

Comment: What does the supplier tell you about those parts?

Comment: The layout guide is the recommended landing pattern for the antenna and the critical components. It does not include the pi network, which is where part #6 and #7 are a part of.

Answer (score 1):

the suppler added an external component for matching. it can come for several reasons:
1. adding a possibility for frequency tuning of thee antenna, single chip will  be used for several frequencies or different bandwidths.
2. adding the matching inside the chip will increase the cost therefor the designer preferred to move out these components.
3. a mistake in  the design that was corrected using external components.

In any case, you need to use the exact instructions written in the datasheet.
Dan

Comment: Usually when designing with such things you really want to build your proposed antenna arrangement on a sample of the board you are actually planning to use, terminated into an end launch SMA, then stick it on a return loss bridge and tune for optimum return loss. The datasheets for these things are always a starting point not an optimised design for your particular board supplier (Er varies significantly in FR4). The series L/C is an oddity, I would normally expect a Pi or L network for matching, it could I suppose just be forming a BPF to clean up whatever transmitter they were using.